# voltage drop on 1 phase

Tags: electrical

I have been having problems with partial power loss. one of the phases drops from 124 volts to 12 volts, sometimes for several minutes but also can last for an hour or more. I changed the main because it was old and wouldn't work right anyway. I am still having the same problems.

Comment: Call the power company.

Comment: I would like some calcification, where are you measuring the voltage and how? How many amps is the system rated for? I would also turn off all power coming in and check the titeness of all connecting components.